# Is there a way to sort a list of lists using an index?

Tags: racket

The code below can sort the list how I want, except that I must use list operations like `first`, `second`, etc. If I only have an integer index, how would I use that to sort?

```
#lang racket
(define lst '(("1" "Z") ("2" "A")))

(sort lst #:key second string<?)
```

I can come up with one solution, which is to create a function or a syntax definition to convert the int to the appropriate operation. Such as if the index is 0, convert it to `first`. But this does not seem pleasant, and this type of list operation only goes up to `tenth`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list-ref`:

```
> (define lst '(1 2 3 4 5))
> (list-ref lst 0)
1
> (list-ref lst 4)
5
```

The first parameter is the list to reference, and the second is the index.

The functions `first` through `tenth`are actually just shorthand for `list-ref`.

Comment: Oh but I cannot use the number returned from `list-ref`. For example, `(sort lst #:key 0 string<?)` does not work. I have to use `first`. Unless I am misunderstanding what you are implying.

Comment: Then can't you use `(sort lst #:key (lambda (l) (list-ref l 0)) string<?)`?

Comment: @Majora320 should you edit your answer to include that pattern?

Answer (score 1):

One can also specify the comparator:

```
(define (sorter ll i)
  (sort ll
        (lambda(a b)
          (if (string<?  (list-ref a i)  (list-ref b i))
              #t #f))))

(define lst '(("1" "Z") ("2" "A")))
(sorter lst 0)
(sorter lst 1)
```

Output:

```
'(("1" "Z") ("2" "A"))
'(("2" "A") ("1" "Z"))
```